# What is the meaning of 0b00 and 0b11 in C/C++?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a small question I hope there is a simple answer there. When programming an Arduino in C/C++ the line "DDRB |= 0b00101000;" occurs. While I know DDRB is the Data Direction Register for port B and the meaning of the numbers after "0b00" (which are the slots 13 to 9), I still don't really know what "0b00" means. 
 
In definitions I only read it means HIGH (while 0b11 means LOW) but what does that mean?

 
Full code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main (void) {

  float seconds = 0.5;
  int time = 1000 * seconds;

  DDRB |= 0b00101000;

  while (1) {

    PORTB |= 0b00001000; 
    _delay_ms(time);
    PORTB &= 0b11110111; 
    PORTB |= 0b00100000;
    _delay_ms(time); 
    PORTB &= 0b11011111; 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A [binary number](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)?

Comment: Are you asking about the `0b` syntax? Or Arduino specific part?

Comment: The b prefix specifies a binary literal, as opposed to a decimal literal. In this case `0b00101000 == 40`, but since you are using it to check bits, it is more readable to express in binary.

Comment: Please note that you are likely writing C++, not C, if you are working with Arduino.

Comment: Thank you for clarification walnut. And thank you CoryKramer I think I'm starting to get it.

Comment: Edit the question to clearly say whether you are asking (a) what is the meaning of `0b00101000` in the C language (as extended by the GNU compiler) or (b) what is the effect of ORing the bits 00101000 into the `DDRB` register or (c) something else. If you do not explain precisely what you are asking, your question will likely be closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

0b means that a number in binary representation is expected.

For Data direction registers, setting the bits to 1 will make the respective lines outputs, and setting to 0 will make them inputs.

The `DDRB |= 0b00101000` will do a binary OR operation between the current value of the bits in `DDRB` with the mask.

This will result in `DDRB = 0b××1×1xxx`, so that means `DDRB` will keep the value for lines 7 and 6. This operation basically sets lines 5 and 3 as Output and leaves the rest as they were.

Answer (score 1):

As you tag your question "Arduino", you might be interested that besides the *standard* c++ 0b... notation the IDE also provides all 8-bit combinations of binary numbers in `B00101000` format, with and without leading zeros.

Usually, hex notation (0x28 in your example) is even easier readable, IMO

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
DDRB |= 0b00101000
```

basically does a bitwise OR with the mask `0b00101000` and reassigns the results to DDRB.

`0b` indicates that whatever comes next should be interpreted as binary, so it's easier to see which bits you are masking.

The code is just setting the bits masked as 1 to HIGH and leaving the others unchanged.